# How to ignore certificate checking in Elasticsearch Nest client?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, https, nest

I am using elastic search and nest client in asp.net core application.
I have gateway which is working on https protocol (https://localhost:8080). My gateway doing only redirect all requests.

When I trying to send request to elastic search through gateway throwing exception as following:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on GET: /es/_cluster/health
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadRequest: Node: http://localhost:8080/es/ Took: 00:00:00.1932641
# OriginalException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
# Request:

# Response:
```

```
var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
elasticClient.ClusterHealth();
```

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/working-with-certificates.html